# How to remove the last space and following digit from a variable python

Tags: python, regex

**my code extracts these lines from a file**

PF00000 name 1

PF00000 name 1

PF00000 AA-CD_name 1

**and I need to remove the last space and number leaving only**

PF00000 name

PF00000 name

PF00000 AA-CD_name

**I tried using:**

```
Var = re.sub(r'.*([0-9])$', "",Var)
```

**and**

```
Var = re.sub(r' \d.*$', "",Var)
```

**but none worked I still get the same**

PF00000 name 1

PF00000 name 1

PF00000 AA-CD_name 1

Comment: Why `.*` for a single space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex:

```
r' [0-9]$'
```

1. Matches single space.
2. `[0-9]` Matches digit. (or use `\d`)
3. `$` Matches end of line.

The code:

```
import re

tests = [
    'PF00000 name 1',
    'PF00000 name 1',
    'PF00000 AA-CD_name 1'
]

regex = re.compile(r' [0-9]$')
for test in tests:
    test = regex.sub('', test)
    print(test)
```

Prints:

```
PF00000 name
PF00000 name
PF00000 AA-CD_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Var = Var.rsplit(maxsplit=1)[0]
```

(BTW, your second attempt looks correct - are you sure there **is** a space and not, for example, a TAB character?)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want:

```
Var = re.sub(r' \d*$', "",Var)
```

Or:

```
fields=Var.split()
Var = ' '.join(fields[:-1])
```

This latter option is good if any amount of whitespace can separate your fields and also has the advantage of not using a regex :)